# How to fetch data from database for dependent dropdown list in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database

Here I am created list in which I created it with the help of array.But I want to fetch all these from the database . so how can i do it.

```html
 this.state = {
      Cities: [],
      Colleges: [],
      Faculties: [],
      selectedCity: "--Choose City--",
      selectedCollege: "--Choose College--",
    };
    this.changeCity = this.changeCity.bind(this);
    this.changeCollege = this.changeCollege.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      Cities: [
        {
          name: "A",
          Colleges: [
            { name: "X", Faculties: ["fy", "sy", "ty"] },
            { name: "Y", Faculties: ["fy", "sy", "ty"] },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "B",
          Colleges: [
            { name: "N", Faculties: ["fy", "sy", "ty"] },
            { name: "M", Faculties: ["fy", "sy", "ty"] },
          ],
        },
        { name: "C", Colleges: [{ name: "O", Faculties: ["fy", "sy", "ty"] }] },
        { name: "D", Colleges: [{ name: "P", Faculties: ["fy", "sy", "ty"] }] },
        { name: "E", Colleges: [{ name: "Q", Faculties: ["fy", "sy", "ty"] }] },
      ],
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can do it but it will not be a good practice. its better to have chained select. First allow the user to select a City and when changed make a request to load the colleges. So you only get what you need.

Comment: can you please explain with the help of  small example

Comment: please check the answer.

Comment: if any further help please comment answer and I will reply and come help.

Comment: if it works for you please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You need to do chained selects In order to 1. be compliant with performance 2. distribute cities and have a lighter code. this code example has been made just for you. (Is not tested, so you have to move forward from here)

inside the select > value option you need to loop over it with either map/forEach/for loop to display cities as well as colleges.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const [cities, setCities] = useState([])
  const [colleges, setCollege] = useState([])

  const fetchCities = () => {
    const options = {}
    const url = "http://mysite.gov/cities/"
    fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setCities(data.cities)
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }

  const fetchColleges = (event) => {
    const options = {}
    const url = `http://mysite.gov/cities/?collegeByCity=${event.target.value}`
    fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setCollege(data.colleges)
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }

  const showMe = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCities()
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {cities.length === 0
        ? ""
        : <select onChange={(event) => fetchColleges(event)}>
          {cities.map((item, index) => {
            return <option value={item}>{item}</option>
          })}
        </select>
      }

      {colleges.length === 0
        ? ""
        : <select onChange={(event) => showMe(event)}>
          {colleges.map((item, index) => {
            return <option value={item}>{item}</option>
          })}
        </select>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```